# Select data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I m currently developing an android app In which I m using firebse as DB.
I want to select a sepcific node and set It's password so how can I do that?
i used this code but it add another password attribute to the selected node.
this is the DB structure and i want to set password value of user toto.

[image]

```
public void resetPassword(){
    //setting connexion parameter
    final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com/users");
    Query query = ref.orderByChild("username").equalTo("toto");


    Firebase statusRef =query.getRef().child("password");
    statusRef.setValue("COMPLETED");



    System.out.println("Hellooooo FBM     ");
}
```

Comment: You probably should not be storing the password inside the user node since firebase have a whole feature to handle authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `query` does not yet have the nodes that match that query. To get the matching nodes, you will have to attach a listener (as shown in the [documentation on reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data)).

A quick example:

```
public void resetPassword(){
    //setting connexion parameter
    final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com/users");
    Query query = ref.orderByChild("username").equalTo("toto");

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
          for (DataSnapshot user: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            Firebase statusRef = user.child("password").getRef();
            statusRef.setValue("COMPLETED");
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
}
```